# Android GridView & ListView Switching

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I'm trying to get a similar effect to how Amazon does their switching of GridView/ListView layouts in an Android app. So far, I have a GridView with 3 columns and when pressing a button, it changes to 1 column (to give the effect of a ListView). A few problems with this though:

1) I want a different layout for when its in ListView mode.
2) The position in the View is not maintained, so the user is back to the top.

At the moment, to fix 1), I'm recreating the Adapter with a new layout, but I'm still stuck with issue 2).

Any ideas on how to do this the same way Amazon has done it?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you'll end up with having 2 distinct controls which will be alternately visible (i. e.: by making one **visible** and the other one **gone**).

Comment: Yes, but then how does it maintain scroll position between the 2? Also, this is all based on an AdapterView (not a plain ListView/GridView).

Comment: Save the selected item position in an integer variable.

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45456602/5973946